# jQuery.parseJSON is not working in wordpress custom php page

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

I receive an base64 encoded json in response of ajax call. Then I decode base64 and got json. Here comes the problem after this, while parsing this json using jQuery.parseJSON() function, i am unable extract it into array.

It 2D Array which I converted into json and then base64, both the processes are compulsory for me.

Here is the code.

```
jQuery.post("http://mydomain.com/contorller/functionname", {}, function(response) {
            if(response != ""){
                var series_json =  decode64(response); 
                var seriesdata =    jQuery.parseJSON(series_json);
                //var sd= seriesdata.series;
                alert(seriesdata["series"]["seriesid"]);
        }
    });
```

decode64 clearly converted response into json. Is there anybody who can help me to overcome this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see the result of `decode64(response)` please?

Comment: Can we also see the JSON itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get jQuery to parse the json and do all of the work by simply plopping "json"  into the get or post function as the last argument. See these two pages for an example:

HTML/JS
http://home.edgemontgeek.com/dev/stackoverflow/14727472/

JSON
http://home.edgemontgeek.com/dev/stackoverflow/14727472/students.json

```
    $.get("students.json", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index,value) {
            $("#console").append("<p>" + value.name + " got a " + value.grade + "</p>");
        });
    }, "json");
```

Comment: Problem is he's getting an encoded instead of the actual json string

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JSON.parse(yourElement)` instead...